# Netty 4 - write ByteBuf directly to channel, bypassing pipeline

Tags: netty

Is it possible with Netty 4 to directly write a `ByteBuf` to a channel without going through the `ChannelOutboundHandler` handlers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it, get the context at the end of the pipeline and write from there: `channel.pipeline().firstContext().write(myByteBuf)`